# Window remove eventListener resize function

Tags: javascript

Having a function doing some things on window load or resize. As soon as something happend I don't need the `window.resize` event listener any more so I tried to remove the `resize event listener` but I don't get it to work.

[Code below is same as in this jsFiddle (you need to resize window so not really possible on stackoverflow code snippet)](https://jsfiddle.net/22oayaLc/1/)

```js
blubb = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
  
  this.blubber = function() {
  
        document.querySelector('.data').innerHTML = window.innerWidth + 'px';

        if(window.innerWidth < 800) {
            this.element.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

            // here remove EventListener
            // is not working
            window.removeEventListener('resize', (function() { this.blubber() }).bind(this));
        } else {
           this.element.style.backgroundColor = 'powderblue';
        }
    };

    this.blubber();
    window.addEventListener('resize', (function() { this.blubber() }).bind(this));
};

blubb(
 document.querySelector('.blubb')
);
```

```css
.blubb {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Change visible area size and reload</h1>
<p>Should be once above 800px and once below 800px</p>
<div class="data"></div>
<div class="blubb"></div>
```

**So if `div.blubb` once changed to orange I would like to remove the event listener which I've tried with:**

```
window.removeEventListener('resize', (function() { this.blubber() }).bind(this));
```

But on resize I see the event is not removed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove event listener which where added using `bind()` you just have to store `listener.bind(this)` in a variable. Because `bind()` is creating a new reference each time its called.

So you could do something like this:

```
var myListener = function(event) { 
... 
};
var myListenerWithContext = myListener.bind(this);
element.addEventListener('event', myListenerWithContext);
element.removeEventListener('event', myListenerWithContext);
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, setting the event handler function to a variable was the trick to getting it to work, the parameters must be 'exactly' the same.

Answer (score 1):

do not use closure, just create a function, then use for both of add and remove event, something like this

```
var blubb = function(element) {
  var evt;
  this.blubber = function() {
    // code...
    if(window.innerWidth < 800) {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', evt);
    }
  };

  evt = this.blubber.bind(this);
  window.addEventListener('resize', evt);
};
```

demo here: https://output.jsbin.com/vuyuvohure

code https://jsbin.com/vuyuvohure/edit?html,js,console